# How to skip slides in Google Slides with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

In Google Slides, it is possible to skip a slide manually by right clicking on it and selecting "Skip slide". In that case, the slide will not show up when being presented.

I cannot seem to recreate this programmatically with Google Apps Script. Does this function exist, or is there any workaround here?

Answer (score 5):

Skipping slides via Slides API is not available at the moment.

There is feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692346 you can "star" it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original answer to this question there are now two methods available to the `Slide`.

[isSkipped()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#isSkipped()) - returning true or false

[setSkipped(boolean)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#setSkipped(Boolean)) - Set as `true` to skip the slide in the presentation mode.